# NSubstitute: Match on any Dictionary with explicit args?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dictionary, testing, nsubstitute

With NSubstitute, how can I match on 'any' Dictionary - so long as it contains a certain set of key-value pairs?

The following will match any Dictionary:

`mockObject.Received().Method(Arg.Any<Dictionary<string, string>>());`

But I'd like to be able to match any Dictionary *so long as it has the given key-value pairs*. For example, I'd like to do something like:

`mockObject.Received().Method(Arg.Any<Dictionary<string, string>> { {"MyKey": "MyValue"} });`

Does something like that exist in NSubstitute?

Comment: Use following : Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            dict.Select(x => (x.Key == "abc") && (x.Value == "xyz"));

Comment: @jdweng -- Thanks for your reply, however I'm not clear on how to bake that logic into the `Received` call for the NSubstitute testing framework. To clarify, my request is not about filtering/matching in code. This question specifically pertains to testing using NSubstitute. Please correct me if I misunderstood.

Comment: NSubstitue and Linq are different layers of the application.  NSubstitue is a class structure while Linq is used to perform queries.  So NSubstitute is equivalent to a Noun and Linq is the Verb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, turns out the mistake was using `Arg.Any` rather than `Arg.Is`.

This worked for me:

`mockObject.Received().Method(Arg.Is<Dictionary<string, string>>(x => x.ContainsKey("MyKey") && x["MyKey"] == "MyValue"));`